# how to insert if statement in Wordpress Functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and I am editing the wordpress **functions.php** file.

My store has two checkout pages, one before admins review orders (**CHECKOUT**) and the other after admins approve orders (**final-checkout**).

I'd like to remove the billing info from the first checkout page, and only display it in the second (final) checkout page.

In the **functions.php** page, I used the following **if statement**, but its not working. I think the if statement is being tested against the **functions.php** page, rather than the checkout page.

```
if ( is_page( 'checkout' )){

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

    function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

If someone can help me only show the billing info on the second checkout page and not the first, it would be very much appreciated

THANKS

Comment: If you use `unset()` like in your function, this will remove this fields before and after, as customer will not be able to enter any data. Your conditional should be inside the function and not outside... For normal checkout page, you should use `if( is_checkout() ){` better than `if ( is_page( 'checkout' )){` … but remember that `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook only works on checkout page, so if you use it, you don't need the conditional function…

Comment: isn't there any separated file for final-checkout page? like final-checkout.php?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please put IF condition inside the function and try again?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

    function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
        if ( is_page( 'checkout' )){
            unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
            unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
            unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
            unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);

            return $fields;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call is_page() before the Global WP_Query instance $wp_query is constructed. Your functions.php is included before $wp_query is constructed. To get around this problem you need to schedule your code to run later after the $wp_query object is constructed using

```
add_action( 'parse_request', function() {
    # At this point $wp_query has been constructed and you can call is_page()
});
```